# Prove that the following sum is 1.

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

I should prove this:

$$\sum_{c_1,c_2,...,c_n}  \dfrac{1}{c_1!c_2!\cdot\cdot\cdot c_n! 1^{c_1}2^{c_2}\cdot\cdot\cdot n^{c_n}} = 1$$

where $c_1+2c_2+...+nc_n = n$ (1)

Evidently, the summation is all over the $n$-tuples ($c_1,c_2,...,c_n$) of non-negative integers for which property (1) is satisfied.

Please, help!

Comment: Each summand is the probability of a permutation in $S_n$ having $c_1$ 1-cycles, $c_2$ 2-cycles, etc.

Answer (score 2):

For $c_1,\dots,c_n$ satisfying $\sum_{k=1}^nkc_k=n$, the number of permutations of $[n]=\{1,\dots,n\}$ having $c_k$ cycles of length $k$ for $k=1,\dots,n$ is

$$\frac{n!}{c_1!c_2!\cdot\cdot\cdot c_n! 1^{c_1}2^{c_2}\cdot\cdot\cdot n^{c_n}}\;;\tag{1}$$

this is, for example, Theorem $4.27$ in Miklós Bóna, *Introduction to Enumerative Combinatorics*. Summing over all such $n$-tuples $\langle c_1,\dots,c_n\rangle$ must yield $n!$, the total number of permutations of $[n]$, and the result is now immediate.

HINT: Let $\pi$ be a permutation with $c_k$ cycles of length $k$ for $k=1,\dots,n$. Write out $\pi$ in cycle notation in such a way that all of the cycles of length $1$ come first, then the cycles of length $2$, and so on. The denominator of $(1)$ is the number of ways to write $\pi$ in that form: $c_k!$ is the number of permutations of the set of $k$-cycles; can you see what $k^{c_k}$ counts?